# How to throw an exception for large integer inputs in java?

Tags: java, exception, input, integer, runtime

I have a particular code in which I am inputting two integer numbers. However, I tried using try catch method with throws IOException but it doesn't help. What I want to do is throw an error if any of the input number very large like 12345678910 - a number greater than 10 digits, so that my code does not throw an error. Due to confidentiality I cannot disclose the code but I assume the code is not required for this. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please clarify _input number is greater than 5 digits (32 bits)_.

Comment: Your question is very unclear: "*However, I tried using try catch method with throws IOException but it doesn't help*" help on what? "*What I want to do is throw an error if ... so that my code does not throw an error*" is also quite confusing. "*but I assume the code is not required for this*" actually code example would be great here, you don't have to put your original code, [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) would be even better.

Comment: I'm sorry check the edits, thanks.

Comment: For now it looks like you should be reading values as string (or maybe BigInteger). Then you can validate it and throw your Exceptions.

Comment: How are you getting the inputs? Through `scanner.nextInt()`? In that case, the method would automatically throw an `InputMismatchError` if the input is larger than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. Why do you want to catch it and throw another exception?

Answer (score 2):

The largest value an int can hold is lesser than the largest 10 digit number.
It is 2,147,483,647. So, the input will be invalid as soon as it is stored in the int variable.

for integers lesser than that boundary, say 5 digits, you can use this.

Create a new `Exception` class :

```
public class CustomException extends Exception
{
  public CustomException(String message)
  {
    super(message);
    //handle the exception here.
  }
}
```

then declare a throws `CustomException` from the method you are using.

```
public void myMethod(int a, int b) throws CustomException {

if(a > 99999 || b > 99999) {
    throw new CustomException("write what message you want printed");
    return;
}

//do your stuff here

}
```

**OR if you want to check for the exception as soon as it is entered for very large numbers**

Assuming you use `Scanner` to take in the number. take the input in the `String` form. and then try converting it to the integer form via a check.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

String number = sc.nextLine();
int num;
double holder = String.valueOf(number);

if(holder>Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
     throw new Exception();
} else
num = (int) holder;
```

This seems to be a very round about way, but it will work for numbers of any length.

You have to do the same for the other number too, so you can put the logic inside a method.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do is to check the length by converting the integer to String, other way is to check the range and throw error message

Example:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
int input = nextInt();

String temp = Integer.toString(input);

if(temp.length > 5 )
throw new IllegalArgumentException ("The value is larger than 5 digits! ");
```

Comment: invalid input, integer value out of range: 12345678910. It throws an error even before it gets to the code.

Comment: I thought the question is with in range and value greater than 5 digits.

Answer (score 0):

As to Sotirios Delimanolis, your question made me a lot of noise. If you mean you need to throw an error if the int is 6 digits, meaning million, then you are looking for somthing like this:

```
 public void checkUnderMillion(int integer) throws IOException {
        if (integer >= 1000000) {
            throw new IOException("Invalid input");
        }
    }
```

That should help if I understood your question.

Comment: `if (integer <= 1000000)` if the input is less than or equal to 1,000,000 throw an exception?

Comment: Thanks beresfordt. Was a typo. And for @kaushaya, is way better if you use a boolean. Change void for boolean. Take out the throws.